# Is there benefit in a generified interface?

Tags: java, generics, interface

Recently in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440198/refactoring-advice-maps-to-pojos/4440371#4440371) it was suggested to me that this:

```
public interface Operation<R extends OperationResult, P extends OperationParam> {

    public R execute(P param);
}
```

Is better than this:

```
public interface Operation {

    public OperationResult execute(OperationParam param);
}
```

I however can't see any benefit in using the first code block over the second one ...

Given that both `OperationResult` and `OperationParam` are interfaces an implementer needs to return a derived class anyway and this seems quite obvious to me.

So do you see any reason the use the first code block over the second one ?

Comment: Are you sure you've meant 'gentrified' not 'generified'?

Comment: A "gentrified" interface? Is that one that becomes popular with the hip, artsy Ruby crowd, only to subsequently undergo luxury renovations by upscale Interface Developers until Joe Open Source Developer can't afford it anymore?

Comment: I meant generified :) (stupid autocorrect ....)

Comment: Thanks for the typo fix Joachim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This way you can declare your `Operation` implementations to return a more specific result, e.g.

```
 class SumOperation implements Operation<SumResult, SumParam>
```

Though whether this is of any value to your application depends entirely on the situation.

**Update:** Of course you could return a more specific result without having a generic interface, but this way you can restrict the input parameters as well.

Comment: hm ... cool, oddly (or not!) I never thought of that ... thanks